# on click function not being called when adding html dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a list in which I have links, on the clicks of those links I am doing stuff. Those links can be added dynamically. For example, I have a input form on the page and when the user fills that form I update the list by appending a new element into the list.

Here is the code for my list

```
<section id="mealPerDay">
@foreach (MealPerDay mpd in Model.GetMealPerDay())
{
    <div class="panel radius @String.Concat("panel_", mpd.Id)">
        <span>@mpd.Name</span>
        <a class="right edit-margin-left edit showHideEditDailyMeal" data-id="@mpd.Id" data-container="mealPerDay" data-cancel=" ">edit</a>
    </div>

}
</section>
```

When the page loads user sees this list and click function is called like this

```
  $('.showHideEditDailyMeal').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).data('container');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var cancel = $(this).data('cancel');
    if (cancel == ' ') {
        $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.cancel-edit').show();
        $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.edit').hide();
        $('#' + container + ' .edit-form.edit_form_' + id).show();
    } else {
        $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.cancel-edit').hide();
        $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.edit').show();
        $('#' + container + ' .edit-form.edit_form_' + id).hide();
    }
});
```

This works fine, now if I add something, I append it to the list like this

```
function newGenerateHtml(result, container, classNameForDelete, classNameForEdit, classNameForShowHideEdit) {
var html = '<div class="panel radius panel_' + result.id + '">';
html += '<span>';
html += result.name;
html += '</span>'
html += '<a class="right edit-margin-left edit ' + classNameForShowHideEdit + '" data-id=' + result.id + ' data-container=' + container + ' data-cancel=" ">edit</a>';
html += '</div>';

return html;
}
```

The mark up I get is similar to the data which load when the page loads. But the click event on the dynamically added data is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are generating HTML dynamically try using [event delegation.](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Instead of

```
$('.showHideEditDailyMeal').click(function (event) {
```

Try

```
$(document.body).on('click','.showHideEditDailyMeal',function(event){
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But can you explain why do we have to do that?

Comment: @mohsinali1317...because element with class `.showHideEditDailyMeal` was not there intially on your page when first time your page loaded...as you are appending html from jquery so in that case you have to use event delegation as specified in answer.

Answer (score 1):

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.showHideEditDailyMeal', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var container = $(this).data('container');
var id = $(this).data('id');
var cancel = $(this).data('cancel');
if (cancel == ' ') {
    $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.cancel-edit').show();
    $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.edit').hide();
    $('#' + container + ' .edit-form.edit_form_' + id).show();
} else {
    $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.cancel-edit').hide();
    $('#' + container + ' div.panel.panel_' + id + ' a.edit').show();
    $('#' + container + ' .edit-form.edit_form_' + id).hide();
}
});
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But can you explain why do we have to do that?

Comment: @mohsinali1317, Because `.on()` also takes care of dynamic elements too, but with `.click()` event you have to make `ready` your script again to work with dynamic element.

Answer (score 1):

use on or live
   Instead of

```
$('.showHideEditDailyMeal').click(function (event) {
Try

$(document.body).on('click','.showHideEditDailyMeal',function(event){
```

or

```
$(document.body).live('click','.showHideEditDailyMeal',function(event){
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But can you explain why do we have to do that?

Comment: using `.live()` is not all a good idea because it is depricated in jquery 1.7 and now removed after jquery 1.9 versions.

Comment: Yes ,But if jquery version is below 1.9 'on' will not work.Thats why i mentioned